# SQL Select pattern like column_name

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

Are there such things as a sql query whereby the results are limited with being contained in the query value.

Normally like is :

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE pattern;
```

I would like it to be

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE pattern LIKE column_name;
```

For example:

```
id   |   val
1    |   c:/tests/one
2    |   c:/tests/two
3    |   c:/
```

I can query using 'c:/tests/two/fail/results', and be returned 2 and 3, as they are sub strings.

Comment: Yes you could do that.

Comment: Whether you do `pattern LIKE Column_Name` or the other way around, it doesn't matter. The expression gets evaluated and returns a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name 
WHERE instr('c:/tests/two/fail/results', column_name) > 0;
```

Comment: This answer really could use more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use LIKE then you could use

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    example
WHERE
    'c:/tests/two/fail/results'
LIKE
    CONCAT(val, '%');
```

Please regard that the right side of LIKE is a pattern and you've got to append the wildcard character '%' to it.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36ff0c/1)

**Note:**

Of course will the solution of juergen d work and may even be faster.

Another issue with my solution is that the column `val` may not contain wild card characters itself. Now the two wild card characters for LIKE are

```
%   Matches any number of characters, even zero characters
_   Matches exactly one character
```

The underscore is not only an allowed character in a file path, it's often used. 
I recommend strongly to use the approach of juergen d.